# URL monitor keeps increasing memory usage

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

I have written a URL monitoring program in vb using .net 4.0.  Basically it sets a timer checks the url every 60 minutes using an htpwebreques/httpwebresponse and sends an email if the url is down.  However the memory used by the application keeps increasing every time the url is checked.  This will obviously eventually cause a problem as the app is designed to run permanently monitoring a website for availability and the monitoring machine will eventually run out of resources.

Code for my CheckURL routine below.  Any advice greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
    Private Sub checkURL()
    Timer1.Stop()
    Dim wReq As HttpWebRequest
    Dim wResp As HttpWebResponse ' WebResponse

    wReq = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
    wReq.Method = "HEAD"
    Try
        wResp = wReq.GetResponse()
        If wResp.StatusCode = 200 Then
                txtResponse.Text = wResp.StatusCode & ": " & wResp.StatusDescription & vbNewLine & "The " & siteName & " is up"

                'Only send success results if specified
                If sendOnFailure = False Then
                    sendResults = True
                End If
            Else txtResponse.Text = "There may be a problem with the " & siteName & vbNewLine & "Please verify manually that it is operational." & vbNewLine & "The response received was:" & vbNewLine & "Status Code: " & wResp.StatusCode & " - " & wResp.StatusDescription
                sendResults = True
            End If

        wResp.Close()
        wResp = Nothing
        wReq = Nothing

    Catch ex As Exception
            txtResponse.Text = "There may be a problem with the " & siteName & vbNewLine & "The error returned was:" & vbNewLine & ex.ToString
            sendResults = True

    End Try

    txtLastCheck.Text = Now.ToString("d MMM yyyy HH:mm")
    setNextCheck()

End Sub
```

Comment: Wrap request in `Using` statements as this ensures your objects get disposed. Right now they are not getting disposed.

Comment: @Zaggler thanks but I tried adding a using statement but get errors "Variable 'wRes' hides a variable in an enclosing block and StatusCode is not a member of WebResponse"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx), which will show you where you have variable type mismatches and may even suggest corrections for you, for example, see where the [`DirectCast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x.aspx) operator is used in the following code.

Second, [`HttpWebResponse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) has a `.Dispose()` method, so you should call that when you have finished using it, or, as Zaggler pointed out, you can use [`Using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx#Remarks) to ensure that unmanaged resources are cleaned up properly, thus removing the memory leak you are concerned with. Note that there may be other similar problems in the code we can't see.

You should *not* set things to `Nothing` in an attempt to get rid of them - doing so messes with the garbage collector and does nothing to ensure their clean disposal.

```
Option Strict On
' ....

Private Sub checkURL()
    timer1.Stop()
    Dim wReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    wReq.Method = "HEAD"

    Try
        Using wResp As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(wReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

            If wResp.StatusCode = 200 Then
                txtResponse.Text = wResp.StatusCode & ": " & wResp.StatusDescription & vbNewLine & "The " & siteName & " is up"

                'Only send success results if specified
                If sendOnFailure = False Then
                    sendResults = True
                End If
            Else txtResponse.Text = "There may be a problem with the " & siteName & vbNewLine & "Please verify manually that it is operational." & vbNewLine & "The response received was:" & vbNewLine & "Status Code: " & wResp.StatusCode & " - " & wResp.StatusDescription
                sendResults = True
            End If

            wResp.Close()
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        txtResponse.Text = "There may be a problem with the " & siteName & vbNewLine & "The error returned was:" & vbNewLine & ex.ToString
        sendResults = True

    End Try

    txtLastCheck.Text = Now.ToString("d MMM yyyy HH:mm")
    setNextCheck()

End Sub
```

Comment: I have implemented the using block as in the above code but am still getting an ongoing memory increase. As a test I added a gc.collect() statement after the End Using and then memory usage stays stable.but I understand this is not good practise. Any ideas what could be wrong it's like the garbage collector is not freeing up resources after objects are disposed.

Comment: It might be that the program memory will increase to some amount and level off, or the garbage collector might do more if the computer comes under memory pressure. Are you creating a lot of strings somewhere else in the program? - if so, a [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) could make a big difference.